# How to connect AWS S3 bucket images to my website

Tags: magento2, product-images, aws

I have installed the extension https://github.com/thaiphan/magento2-s3/ for connect to S3 bucket.

When I proceed to sync button then images not uploaded proper format on AWS S3. Please check the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this module not fully compatible with magento 2.3
you need to execute 
php bin/magento s3:storage:export
to manually sync media